# Get more information from Oracle audit trail

Tags: oracle, audit

I just turned on auditing for an Oracle 11g database. I'm interested in getting more information about each event; for example, when I see a `CREATE_INDEX` event, I'd like to know which field was indexed. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use one of the below settings:

[AUDIT_TRAIL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams017.htm#REFRN10006)

> - db, extended
>
> Performs all actions of AUDIT_TRAIL=db, and **also populates the SQL
>   bind and SQL text CLOB-type columns** of the SYS.AUD$ table, when
>   available. These two columns are populated only when this parameter is
>   specified.
>
> - xml, extended
>
> Performs all actions of AUDIT_TRAIL=xml, and **includes SQL text and SQL
>   bind information** in the audit trail.

```
alter system set AUDIT_TRAIL=db, extended scope=spfile;
shutdown immediate
startup
```

Comment: Might want to add a warning that executing your code will shut the database down.

Comment: @MguerraTorres - one would hope that the command "shutdown immediate" would be a pretty strong clue that the db will get shut down.  But unfortunately, there are people out there who will blindly copy and execute code from the internet without actually thinking about what it is doing.

Comment: @EdStevens agreed.  That was the main reason for my comment.  It seems as "harmless" as a RECONFIGURE command in SQL Server but it (SHUTDOWN)  soooo much worse.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reconfigure-transact-sql